# Can't preview Wordpress drafts with nginx reverse proxy setup

Tags: wordpress, nginx, reverse-proxy

When trying to preview drafts, I get the Wordpress error:

```
Sorry, you are not allowed to preview posts.
```

My installation is a little unique:

- My primary web app is served by nginx on one server (primary.com)
- My Wordpress installation is served by apache on a different server (blog.com)
- My nginx config proxies all `/blog` traffic on the first server to the Wordpress server

nginx reverse proxy configuration looks like this:

```
  location /blog {
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_pass https://blog.com:443;
   proxy_connect_timeout        300;
   proxy_send_timeout           300;
   proxy_read_timeout           300;
   send_timeout                 300;
   proxy_redirect off;
  }
```

In my my `wp-config.php` file, I define:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';

define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://blog.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://primary.com/blog');
```

Everything seems to work really well except for previewing drafts. Other Stackoverflow answers mention that setting `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` to the same URL should fix the problem, but this is not a viable solution for my reverse proxy situation.

Any help is greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: I reached the end of the internet!!!  Did you ever find a solution?  Josh, you're my only hope... lol

Comment: Hey Rob, unfortunately I don't believe I ever did. Our team just ended up living with it, and we eventually consolidated everything to a single server. Sorry to let you down!